# How to turn off responsive menu in touchfolio theme?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm replacing the existing menu in [Touchfolio](http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/demo/) Wordpress theme and I'm trying to figure out how to turn off the responsiveness of the current menu.

I weeded out all associated media queries in css, but something triggers the responsive menu on the slider plugin side. I believe the breakpoint is set to 800px, but I couldn't find anything referring to this within the script.

Here's the link to the existing script from the demo site: http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/demo/wp-content/themes/touchfolio/js/jquery.slider-pack.js

Answer (score 0):

You could start by gutting the `displayMobileMenu` function in the theme's main.js. It looks like this:

```
displayMobileMenu = function() {
            if(mobileMenu) {
                mobileMenu.css('display', 'block').removeClass('menu-close-button');
                _menusContainer.hide().css({ height : 0 });
                return;
            } 

            var headerHeight = _headerSideMenu.height();
            mobileMenu = $('<a class="menu-button"><i class="menu-button-icon"></i>menu</a>');
            $('.top-logo-group').after(mobileMenu);

            setTimeout(function() {
                var height = _menusContainer.height();
                _menusContainer.hide().css({ height : 0 , top: _headerSideMenu.height()});

                mobileMenu.bind('click.mobilemenu',function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(isMenuAnimating) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    mobileMenu.toggleClass('menu-close-button');

                    if ( _menusContainer.is(':visible') ) {
                            _menusContainer.animate({ height: 0 }, { duration: 300, complete: function () {
                            _menusContainer.hide();
                        } 
                    });
                    } else {
                        _menusContainer.show().animate({ height : height }, { duration: 300 });
                    }
                    isMenuAnimating = false;
                    return false;
                });
            }, 0);

        },
```

But could just as easily look like this:

```
displayMobileMenu = function() {},
```

There's still some more stuff altering the menu on smaller screens, but it doesn't fully collapse.